# Workflow logic for multiple-approval process using logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a Workflow logic for the multiple-approval process using logic apps.

My requirement is we have 3 approvers 2 are primary 1 is secondary approver.
If one of the primary approvers is not approved in 15 minutes it will go to a secondary approver.
If one of the primary approvers is rejected it will stop the process.
If both primary approvers have approved the file will move to another location.

Could you please someone help me with this.